optional DOM element in ZOD validation
(the two optional fields are optional and is attached/removed to DOM through a boolean state value)
It's a react hook form using ZOD for schema validation. Besides that it's in next js, using react query, axios

I am rendering two password fields(password, confirmPassword) through a boolean state
they are optional if not in DOM
be equal and mandatory to fill in if rendered


type EditProfile = z.infer<typeof editProfileSchema>;


  const {
    control,
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    setValue,
  } = useForm<EditProfile>({
    resolver: zodResolver(editProfileSchema),
  });


  const editProfileMutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: updateProfileData,
    onSuccess: () => {
      toast.success("Profile edited successfully", {
        duration: 1800,
      });
      router.replace("/welcome");
    },
  });


  const handleFormSubmit = (data: any) => {
    const { ["confirmPassword"]: excluded, ...actual } = data;
    const obj = { ...actual };
    if (croppedImage) {
      obj.profile_image = croppedImage;
    }
    editProfileMutation.mutate({
      profile: {
        ...obj,
      },
    });
  };


//...

<form
  data-cy="section-wrapper"
  className="scrollbar grow overflow-y-scroll scroll-smooth pb-10"
  id="specific-root"
  onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleFormSubmit)}
 >

//...

<AnimatePresence>
                        {pwdChange && (
                          <motion.div
                            className="grow"
                            initial={{ scale: 0 }}
                            animate={{ scale: 1 }}
                            exit={{ scale: 0 }}
                            transition={{ duration: 0.3 }}
                          >
                            {/* pwd */}
                            <InputWrapper
                              backgroundColor="#FECB46"
                              className="mb-5"
                            >
                              <input
                                type="password"
                                placeholder="placeholder"
                                id="password"
                                className="input-primary peer h-14 w-full text-sm"
                                {...register("password")}
                              />
                              {errors.password && (
                                <p className="mt-2 text-sm text-red-400">
                                  {errors.password.message}
                                </p>
                              )}
                              <label
                                htmlFor="password"
                                className="label-primary"
                              >
                                password
                              </label>
                            </InputWrapper>


                            {/* confirm pwd */}
                            <InputWrapper backgroundColor="#FECB46">
                              <input
                                type="password"
                                placeholder="placeholder"
                                id="confirmPassword"
                                className="input-primary peer h-14 w-full text-sm"
                                {...register("confirmPassword")}
                              />
                              {errors.confirmPassword && (
                                <p className="mt-2 text-sm text-red-400">
                                  {errors.confirmPassword.message}
                                </p>
                              )}
                              <label
                                htmlFor="confirmPassword"
                                className="label-primary"
                              >
                                confirm password
                              </label>
                            </InputWrapper>
                          </motion.div>
                        )}
                      </AnimatePresence>
    //...

<form/>
//...

ZOD schema:

const editProfileSchema = z
  .object({
//...
    password: z
      .string()
      .min(8, { message: "min 8 chars required" })
      .optional()
      .or(z.literal("")),
    confirmPassword: z.string().optional().or(z.literal("")),
//...
      })
  .refine((data) => data.password === data.confirmPassword, {
    message: "password do not match",
    path: ["confirmPassword"],
  });
```.

- I tried registering/unregistering through useEffect,(if rendered or not) didn't working
- so made them optional and checked equality with `refine` method

But i feel these two are optional fields that is not always present inside form, 
then why should ZOD validation be applied to them until not in DOM

